# Invoke parent controller while loading child controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-routing

I have the parent view defined as:

```
<div ng-app="myProSupMod" ng-controller="DefaultController" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/logo.jpg" />
                <b class="projectTitle">Production Support Tool</b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="DefaultProps.UserDivVisible" class="page-header"
             style="font-weight:bold;height:30px;border-bottom:1px solid #d1d1d4;width:100%">
           <div style="float:right;"><span style="margin-right:10px;">
                Welcome 
              <a class="text-success" href="#">
                {{DefaultProps.LoggedInUsername }}
              </a></span>|
              <a href="#" style="margin-left:5px;" class="text-danger"
                 ng-click="LogUserOut()">Logout
              </a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Its controller:

```
myProSupMod.controller("DefaultController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', 
'$location', '$route', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $route) {

    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedInUsername")) {
        $scope.DefaultProps = {
            LoggedInUsername: "",
            UserDivVisible: false 
        };
        $location.path('/');
    }
    else {
        $scope.DefaultProps = { 
            LoggedInUsername: sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedInUsername"),
            UserDivVisible: true 
        };
    }
    $scope.LogUserOut = function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("UserDivVisible", false)
        $location.path('/')
    }
}])
```

And one of my child child controller is like

```
myProSupMod.controller("LoginController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', 
    '$uibModal', 'LoginService', '$location', function ($scope, $rootScope, 
    $uibModal, LoginService, $location) {

    $scope.DefaultProps.LoggedInUsername = ""
    $scope.DefaultProps.UserDivVisible = false
    $scope.Login = {
        Username: '',
        Password: '',
        Error: '',
        validateLogin: function () {
            $scope.Login.Error = ''
            $scope.DefaultProps.LoggedInUsername = 
                sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedInUsername")
            $scope.DefaultProps.UserDivVisible = 
                sessionStorage.getItem("UserDivVisible")
            $scope.Login.Username = $scope.Login.Password = ''
                $location.path('/Home')  
        }
    }
}])
```

The statements

```
$scope.DefaultProps.LoggedInUsername=sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedInUsername")
```

and

```
$scope.DefaultProps.UserDivVisible =sessionStorage.getItem("UserDivVisible")
```

are really changing the values of the properties in the "Default" controller but routing to an other view both the "Default" controller properties "LoggedInUsername" and "UserDivVisible" are gone.It looks like i may need to have both the above statements in every other view i'm going to navigate to.

Is there an other way?

"Default" view being the parent, the controller is invoked only once at the start of the application upon navigating to other view the "Default" controller is never invoked. 
But if i reload any page by clicking "reload" on the browser or hitting "enter" on the URL i see the "Default" controller being invoked, which is what i want to happen when i'm also navigating to other view via angular routing.

Comment: One approach is to move the login functions to a service. Then they can be invoked by each view controller as it loads.

Comment: If you have, say, an outer `div` with its controller and then an inner `div` with its own controller, the inner controller has visibility of the outer. You can access methods of the parent IF they are part of the `$scope` (of the outer controller).

Comment: @FDavidov Thanks for the response, Nested controller has access to parent controller methods and properties alright but shouldn't parent controller be invoked every time i navigate to a view?? By what you're saying i should always set the properties of parent controller in the controller where i'm navigating from, like i did in the login controller. I wonder if there is another way

Comment: @georgeawg could you please elaborate??

Comment: I don't see why you would need to invoke the MAIN controller at all. Within the inner controller you will always get access to its parent's elements. If, for instance, you change view, the new one will also get access (no need to invoke anything. It is like many programming languages where functions within a _function_ have access to the _function's_ scope.

Comment: @FDavidov the if else condition helps me prevail the user info accros the views for me, that is why i need it to be invoked. I'm hoping that if the parent controller is invoked I don't have to make an explicit call to any function

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, here is a simplified template:

```
<div ng-app="myProSupMod" ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <div ng-show="DefaultProps.LoggedInUsername">
        Welcome  {{DefaultProps.LoggedInUsername}}
        <button ng-click="LogUserOut()">Logout<button>
    </div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Make the controller lightweight:

```
app.controller("DefaultController", function($scope, LoginService) {
    $scope.DefaultProps = LoginService.getProps();
    $scope.LogUserOut = function () {
        LoginService.logout();
    };
})
```

With the functions inside a service, they can be called by any controller and they are encapsulated in a way that makes the code easier to understand, debug, and maintain.